# Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments in case of nsmutable array

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I am new to Swift, can u plz suggest me why these errors are happening

```
{
var profArr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


for index in 1...<profArr.count
        {
            var joomlaID : NSString = [dbManager?.getZoomlaID(profArr[index]["firmUserId"] as String)];  

// while using this in loop getting **could not find overload**  error.
        }



func getZoomlaID (firmUser : NSString) -> NSString
    {
        var zoomlaId : NSString

        var dbPath: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("dbPath")

        var db = FMDatabase(path: dbPath as! String)

        db?.open()

        if var rsltSet : FMResultSet! = db!.executeQuery("Select JoomlaUserID From org_firm_users where FirmUserID like ('\(firmUser)')",  withArgumentsInArray: nil)  //Here again getting error Unprintable ASCII character.
        {
            while (rsltSet.next())
            {
                print(rsltSet.resultDictionary())

                zoomlaId = (rsltSet.resultDictionary() as NSDictionary).valueForKey("JoomlaUserID") as! NSString     
            }
        }

        else
        {
            println("select failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        db?.close()

        return zoomlaId
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include the error you are talking about and the code you've provided is incomplete. Fix the sample code and add the error you are facing.

Comment: You did not post the "errors", please add them.

Comment: i am new to stack over flow. plz guide me how to add code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the line `for index in 1...<profArr.count` you are adding an unwanted `.<` to loop declaration, it should be something like this: `for index in 1..profArr.count`

`...` means from-to inclusive and `..` means from-to non-inclusive.

e.g. `1..3` means 1,2,3 but `1..3` means 1,2

Comment: Actually he's probably adding an unwanted . not an unwanted <

Comment: for index in 1..<profArr.count
        {
            var joomlaID : NSString = [dbManager?.getZoomlaID(profArr[index]["firmUserId"] as String)];
        }

In this last line, i am getting issue

Comment: you're right he as adding an extra `.<` , will fix the answer

Comment: @SimranJit, you don't need to add the less than operator (`<`), it is already there (implicitly), read the answer one more time.

Comment: @M.Porooshani Yes u r ryt, but i am getting issue in other line.. My concern is not with loop

Comment: well, in that case I think it means `getZoomlaID ` has more or less parameters that you've provided. Check the function for it's interface and see if you are providing only the required inputs. (P.S. Please avoid abbreviating full words, u r ryt == you are right, that's more appropriate for chat not a technical community.)